# THROW is not returning the correct line number when variables are used

Tags: sql-server

An often mentioned benefit of THROW in a CATCH block is that it returns correct line number where the error occurred. 
I noticed that it only does this when I use THROW without any variables.
Using the format below, with my own error number and message returns the line number of the THROW itself (just like RAISERROR does).

```
THROW 50055, 'my message', 1;
```

Is this to be expected and a known flaw or am I doing something wrong?

*I'm using SQL Server 2017 CU20.*

Comment: SQL Server is not unique in this respect. The same applies with other languages that use `throw..catch` such as C#

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this to be expected and a known flaw or am I doing something wrong?

Yes, it is the expected behavior. You've generated a new error message, and it originates at the call site of `THROW ...`.  This is why you should favor just `THROW;` or you need to encapsulate all the relevant error context information in your message.